# Measure time taken by a fetch request only when the page is active

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to measure how much time a network request is taking:

```js
let time = performance.now();

await fetch('example.com', { method: 'PUT', body: '...' });

let requestTime = performance.now() - time;
```

However, on some mobile browsers (like Safari), when the user switches apps (e.g. go from Safari to another app) in the middle of the request, the rest of the code only executes when the user switches back to Safari. (ps: I can't reproduce this on my Windows browser)

This is causing our metrics to be distorted, since some users return hours later to finish the process, causing `requestTime` to be misleading.

#### Question

How can I take into account only the time the user actually spent waiting for the request to finish? Or at least detect this happened so I can discard this metric.

I don't mind having to switch to a non-native lib (instead of `fetch`) with builtin functionalitites to help me with this.

I have no control over the endpoint I'm calling, so I can't return the time taken from there.

Comment: If a process is suspended I don't see how you can get accurate data?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree. But perhaps there's a way to detect that the browser "lost focus" and take it into account when measuring time elapsed? Or at least some way I can detect this happened and discard this metric?

Comment: Maybe use PageVisibility api? When visibility changes, check if request is ongoing, and stop timer or something like this.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would retain accuracy *might* be a service worker as that is how you ensure you don't get throttled by loss of focus. But that may not apply when a mobile app loses focus.